# Codeigniter error on moving the website from localhost to server

Tags: php, codeigniter

We are using Code Igniter version 2.2 to develop an application. We have created it locally and it works fine however when uploaded onto the server we get the following error:

An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested file: Abc/xyz.php 
(file name changed for question)

Code in controller:

```
class Abc extends CI_Controller {

   public function xyz(){

     $this->load->view(__CLASS__."/".__FUNCTION__);

  }
```

When I modify the code to the following the page appears:

```
class Abc extends CI_Controller {

   public function xyz(){

       $this->load->view("Abc/xyz");

   }
```

How can I get the above code run using Class & Function?

Thanks for your time & efforts.

Comment: Resolved it; had erroneously named the folder in lower case..

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `echo __CLASS__."/".__FUNCTION__` to debug this value on server.